# SQL Select random rows partitioned by a column

Tags: sql, random

I have a dataset looks like this

```
| Country    | id |
-------------------
| a       | 5  |
| a       | 1  |
| a       | 2  |
| b       | 1  |
| b       | 5  |
| b       | 4  |
| b       | 7  |
| c       | 5  |
| c       | 1  |
| c       | 2  |
```

and i need a query which returns 2 random values from where country in ('a', 'c'):

```
| Country | id |
------------------
| a       | 2 |  -- Two random rows from Country = 'a'
| a       | 1 | 
| c       | 1 |
| c       | 5 | --Two random rows from Country = 'c'
```

Comment: Tag one RDBMS.  There's not a standard SQL solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select Country, id from
(select Country, 
id,
row_number() over(partition by Country order by rand()) as rn
from table_name
) t
where Country in ('a', 'c') and rn <= 2
```

Replace `rand()` with `random()` if you're using Postgres or `newid()` in SQL Server.

Comment: What to do for unequal-sized samples?